# Filtering in angularjs inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering

im trying to filter inside a ngRepeat and i'm getting always the same error with all filters using `filter`, here i put the code and the error:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchOd.name"/>
<li ng-repeat="od in opdata[odTag] | filter:searchOd as odFiltered">
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: boolean is not a function
at angular.min.js:16709
at $parseFilter (angular.min.js:12155)
at Object.regularInterceptedExpression (angular.min.js:12851)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.min.js:14235)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.min.js:14506)
at done (angular.min.js:9659)
at completeRequest (angular.min.js:9849)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.min.js:9790)
```

I try to export opdata[odTag] using {{opdata[odTag] | json}} and put in in a plunkr but in plunkr it works!! what i'm doing wrong?

This is how i'm doing now without `filter`:

```
.filter('byDistrict', function() {
    return function(items, id_district) {
        var filtered = [];
        if(!id_district) return items;
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            if(item.id_district == id_district) filtered.push(item);
        });
        return filtered;
    }
})
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

As is said in the plunkr it works but i put here: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rfeNg2UGBR78JkHDQtfb?p=preview)

Comment: pls share your plunkr

Comment: If the ng-model is to "searchOd.name", shouldn't the filtering be made with  "{name: searchOd.name}" too? Just a possible idea...

Comment: @DonJuwe updated with plunkr but in the plunkr it works :'(

Comment: `I try to export opdata[odTag] using {{opdata[odTag] | json}} and put in in a plunkr but in plunkr it works!!` -- You plunker seems to be a little different from what you say here. Can you be a little more clear.

Comment: opdata[odtag] is setted via $http, so i used {{ opdata[odtag] | json }} in my template to import the data to plunkr, the only thing i want is to filter via input the data, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code. But you are using Angular 1.2.x where the "as results" feature is part of Angular 1.3+

Comment: Sorry for that too, in my web i'm using angular 1.3.x